# Run Selenium Chrome WebDriver on Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have : **ASP.NET Core2 App** + **Selenium** to automate some actions with browser.

It works perfect on local.Use the latest versions of all nuget and exe.

After deploy to Azure have problems on create Webdriver.

**I tried:**

- Include .exe files to folder and use it like :

new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService("./CORE/ExeFiles"), chromeOptions);

- Run Job with standalone RemoteWebServer: Cant connect to it + Job disappears after Start-Stop site.
- Run .exe files as service - dead end;
- **Run .exe file from CMD  with code: RemoteWebServer on 4444 port OK**, but I can't connect to it.

Read about some Firewall or Antivirus blocking stuff but cant find where to configure necessary properties on Azure.

**How can I use Selenium on Azure?**
Some simplest example pls??, I'm fighting with this for 3 days =(

P.S. Also find this article https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks
and THIS in the end:

**Unsuported:**
PhantomJS/Selenium: tries to connect to local address, and also uses GDI+.

**Alternatives? How to use Selenium on Azure?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work on App Service and you already found the limits and limitations page that explains it.

That being said, it works just fine on a Cloud Service (with Roles), yes the [good ol' Cloud Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me).

WebRole sample —

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace WebRole1.Controllers
{
    public class PhantomController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Run PhantomJS UI tests against the specified URL
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="URL">URL to test</param>
        public string Get(string URL)
        {
            string result = UITests.Test(URL);
            return result;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UITests class
    /// </summary>
    public class UITests
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Test implementation
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="URL">URL to test</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Test(string URL)
        {
            // Initialize the Chrome Driver
            // Place phantomjs.exe driver in the project root,
            // meaning same folder as WebRole.cs
            using (var driver = new PhantomJSDriver())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Go to the home page
                    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);

                    IWebElement input;
                    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(
                        driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

                    Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> _emailInputIsVisible =
                        ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("email"));
                    wait.Until(_emailInputIsVisible);
                    input = driver.FindElementById("email");
                    input.SendKeys("imposter@mailinator.com");
                    driver.FindElementById("submit").Click();
                    var alertbox = driver.FindElementById("alert");
                    if (alertbox.Text.Contains("disposable"))
                    {
                        return "PASS";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "FAIL: alertbox.Text should contain " + 
                            "the word 'disposable'";
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return $"FAIL: {ex.Message}";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can look at [Azure Container Instances](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/) with [Headless Chrome](https://github.com/snobu/what-is-love-baby-dont-hurt-me-no-mo). There's a [.NET SDK as well](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp).

Comment: As a solution - I created Virtual Machine and set up site on IIS.

Answer (score 4):

WELL, GOOD NEWS!!

I got the following working

**Azure Web job** hosted along a website in **Azure App Service (S1 App Service plan)** + **Selenium C#** + **Browserless.io** for running remote headless chrome.

Make sure you install only 2 the following 2 Nuget Packages -

1. Selenium.WebDriver
2. Selenium.Support

That's it.

I had issues when I installed ChromeDriver package also and then the ChromeDriver.exe was the cause of problems on Azure. So stay away from running the browser on Azure. Just think of it as the controller which runs the browser as service remotely.

Comment: Do you have any sample code for it? Where would the headless chrome runs without having a VM? Does your webjob executes a console exe containing selenium tests?

Comment: Browserless.io for running remote headless chrome -- This is a separate service provided by browserless.io, not housed inside your webjob or VM - think of it like a webservice call being made from your webjob. I use a webjob which executes an exe, which runs selenium code for remote browser (on browserless.io)  - Please see the sample code in the below comment

Answer (score 1):

```
string apikey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BROWSERLESS_API_KEY"];
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
// Set launch args similar to puppeteer's for best performance
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-background-timer-throttling");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-breakpad");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-features=TranslateUI,BlinkGenPropertyTrees");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-ipc-flooding-protection");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-renderer-backgrounding");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--force-color-profile=srgb");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--hide-scrollbars");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--metrics-recording-only");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--mute-audio");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("browserless.token", apikey, true);
using (var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("https://chrome.browserless.io/webdriver"), chromeOptions.ToCapabilities()))
{
//Your selenium code
}
```

Comment: This is quite helpful. Thanks

Comment: This content about browserless, is also described in the documentation here: https://docs.browserless.io/docs/dotnet.html

Answer (score -3):

I was facing the same errors and I tried this and Its working for me.
I added the chromedriver.exe in the repo itself and gave relative path in the code. It is working fine as it works in local env.

[Chromedriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5nW8.png)