# How to execute Chrome-webdriver in Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: azure, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

You are about to run the chrome-webdriver on an azure cloud service.

However, the following error occurs.

`chrome_webdriver sample code`

```
from selenium import webdriver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/.chromedriver.exe') 
url = "https://www.instagram.com/" 
driver.get(url)
```

[image]

- If you look at the picture, I put the chrome-driver file in the `same directory as .ipynb`
- The path was set to './chromedriver.exe', `but an error occurred.`

**Other attempted methods**

```
1. driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"\chromedriver.exe")
2. driver = webdriver.Chrome("\\chromedriver.exe")
3. driver = webdriver.Chrome("/chromedriver.exe")
```

-> I tried a different method, but an error occurred.

> how to chrome-webdriver excute in azure cloud service?

**Vova Bilyachat Update posts for comments**

```
1. driver = webdriver.Chrome('./Users/admin/chromedriver.exe')
-> Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
2. driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
-> OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './chromedriver.exe'
```

**update post2**
[image]

Comment: OSError are you sure that driver is for your OS? I mean that you  have right driver for right OS

Comment: I tried the chromewebdriver with window, linux, but still got an error.

Comment: So if you deploy linux do you still get OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './chromedriver.exe'?

Comment: When you deploy linux i think it should not be chromedriver.exe. I just unzipped file please change into ./chromedriver

Comment: i tried , but an error occurred.

Comment: When you say error occur please update your question. Because error can help to solve this problem

Comment: @VovaBilyachat update now

Comment: You did not updated code :( driver = webdriver.Chrome('/.chromedriver')

Comment: See there is no .exe

Comment: update now sry.

Comment: Now i am afraid that you need to have chrome installed there :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path have a look here

Comment: For the link you gave me, I tried everything, but I couldn't resolve it. I'm sad

Comment: I know i think problem is that there is no chrome browser installed :(

Comment: I'm so sad that I haven't solved this problem for a long time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Selenium Chrome WebDriver on Azure Cloud Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51958882/run-selenium-chrome-webdriver-on-azure-cloud-service)

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is that you set path "/chromedriver.exe" which is looking for file in root folder, change it to "./chromedriver.exe" where **"./"** means start from folder you execute script

Also you must be sure that you deployed right driver for right [Operating System](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=91.0.4472.19/)

And since its linux use

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/.chromedriver')
```

Comment: Biilyachat I performed the command as you said, but an error occurred.
Posting updated successfully.